# Find $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor}{x^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I found this cool problem in a textbook. I googled it and used MSE's search tool to check if it has been asked before or not, but it seems that it hasn't been asked before.

Find the function $f(x)$  that the following limit defines: $$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor}{x^n}$$

I have already solved it and I have shared my solution as an answer. Other solutions are welcome too.

Comment: @ClementYung Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Interesting question and thanks for sharing, but would it be more appropriate to share just the question, then put your solutions as an answer (then accepting it)?

Comment: @ClementYung Sure. That's a good idea. I'll edit my question and post the solution as an answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: We know that $x-1<\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$, hence

$$x + \cdots + x^n - n < \lfloor x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor \leq x + \cdots + x^n$$

Dividing both sides by $x^n$
$$\frac{x + \cdots + x^n}{x^n} - \frac{n}{x^n} < \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor}{x^n} \leq \frac{x + \cdots + x^n}{x^n}$$

Using the identity $x+\cdots+x^n = \frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, we have

$$\frac{x}{x-1}\cdot \frac{x^n-x}{x^n} - \frac{n}{x^n} < \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor}{x^n} \leq \frac{x}{x-1}\cdot \frac{x^n-x}{x^n}$$

If $|x|>1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{x^n} = 0$. To prove it, first ssume $x>1$, we can write it as $x=1+r$ where $r>0$, hence

$$x^n=(1+r)^n > 1+nr+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}r^2$$
$$0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{x^n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{1+nr+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}r^2}=0$$

For the case $x<-1$, just replace $x$ with $(-x)>1$ and notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n}{(-x)^n} = 0$.

Hence, for $|x| > 1$, the squeeze theorem proves that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor}{x^n} = \frac{x}{x-1}$$

For $0<x<1$, $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)$ is undefined on $[-1,0] \cup \{1\}$. Q.E.D.

Comment: And for $\;x=1\;$ we get that $\;f\;$ is also undefined.

Comment: @DonAntonio Exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Nitpicking: The inequality$ x^n=(1+r)^n>1+nr +\binom {n}{2}r^2$ is only valid for $n\ge 3.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\lfloor t\rfloor=t-\{t\}$, the numerator is a geometric progression from $x$ to $x^n$, minus a number that does not exceed $n$.

Hence, for $|x|>1$,

$$\frac {x^{n+1}-x}{(x-1)x^n}\to\frac x{x-1}$$ while $$-\frac n{x^n}\to0.$$

For $x=1$, $\dfrac n1\to\infty$.

For $0<x<1$, $\dfrac{n\cdot0}{x^n}\to0$.

For $x=0$, not defined.

For $-1<x<0$, $-\dfrac n{2x^n}\to-\infty$.

For $x=-1$, alternatively $-\dfrac1{x^n}$ and $0$, undefined.